# What is the right way to work with ISODate in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to call a mongodb collection with mongoose but I am having trouble using dates in the call

```
const siteReviews = await Review.countDocuments({
  'clientId': clientObj.ClientBrandID, 
  'siteSource': 'SomeSite', 
  'reviewDate':{
      $gt:"2018-12-24T18:04:47.806Z",
      $lt:"2019-04-03T17:04:47.806Z"
  }
})
```

I know for a fact that I have data between these two dates but i get 0 back.I have also tried to use ISODate("") directly in the code but it is breaking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, You have defined the `type` of the `reviewDate` field as `Date` in your schema and here you are passing it as `String`.

So basically you need to convert the `String` date to `Date` Object and can be easily done using [**`moment`**](https://momentjs.com/) library

```
const googleReviews = await Review.countDocuments({
  clientId: clientObj.ClientBrandID,
  siteSource: "SomeSite",
  reviewDate: {
    $gt: moment("2018-12-24T18:04:47.806Z").toDate(),
    $lt: moment("2019-04-03T17:04:47.806Z").toDate()
  }
});
```