# Mongodb get documents between dates(Stored as string in the format "20-05-2019")

Tags: mongodb

This is the sample document that I have:

```
{ 
  "timestamp" : "1558341279777",
  "date" : "20-05-2019",
  "hour" : "14",
  "month" : "5",
  "time" : "14:4:39",
  "weekDay" : "Monday"
}
```

I want to query documents between given dates. Say between "26-05-2019" and "01-06-2019".
The following is the query that I tried:

```
db.getCollection('messagelogs').find({'date': {'$gte': '20-05-2019', '$lt': '31-05-2019'}})
```

The problem with the above query is that it does string comparison, which doesnt always return the correct result when we query for dates. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Hi Tony, what is the datatype of Date field?

Comment: @PriyankaKariya, the data type of date field is string

Comment: Hi tony, Please look into this answer. Hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647245/use-gte-and-lte-mongo-operator-if-date-is-in-string-format-in-mongodb

Comment: The answer which I have marked with duplicate shows you the various approaches ***"how to query with string dates"***. In my opinion it is a false way to store dates in string format. It would be better if you re-create your [collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834596/mongodb-querying-between-a-time-range-of-hours) and insert dates as `Date` type.

Comment: @Fanpark I completely agree with you, but my requirement forced me to store the date in string format, because I'm directly fetching these dates from db and displaying in the client side. I have hundreds of documents and I thought converting each Date type field into string in the program would be difficult. I would really appreciate if you can find a solution to my problem. Let me know if you need more details regarding my issue

Comment: ***if you can find a solution to my problem*** That is what I have suggested you in the above comment. Use an `$out` aggregation which will create a new collection for you as shown in the link in the above comment. Then it will be easier to you to direct query with date type.  Another solution is on top of the question(duplicate)

Comment: @Fanpark creating another collection/field will be even more difficult for me, because I will have to update and change the logic in my code wherever I'm referring the collection to. The question you have marked duplicate almost worked for me, only that I'm having a hard time passing 'ISODate' from my code(in Javascript). Although the solution is working absolutely fine in mongoshell. I have commented more details about the issue I'm facing in the answer below. Kindly have a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55500690/what-is-the-right-way-to-work-with-isodate-in-mongoose/55500735#55500735

Comment: @Fanpark The problem here is that I have my dates in the format "20-05-2019"(as String), and in the solution you have given above, even though the dates are string, its in correct format. So the above solution doesnt solve mine :(
Any other ideas?

Comment: Please create a new question and clearly describe your problem.

Comment: @Fanpark I have created a new question here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359921/mongodb-query-documents-between-two-dateswhich-is-in-string-format-20-05-2019

Comment: @Fanpark can you kindly check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359921/mongodb-query-documents-between-two-dateswhich-is-in-string-format-20-05-2019

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
    db.collection.find({
      "$expr": {
        "$and": [
      {
        "$gte": [
          { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$date, "format": "%m-%d-%Y" }},
          ISODate("2019-05-26T00:00:00Z")
        ]
      },
      {
        "$lte": [
          { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$date", "format": "%m-%d-%Y" }},
          ISODate("2019-06-15T23:59:59Z")
        ]
      }
    ]
     }
    })
```

Comment: Priyanka, the query is fine but I want to execute this query from my javascript application where I cant use 'ISODate("2019-05-26T00:00:00Z")' since its undefined. I tried converting the date using new Date(), but that didnt seem to work. Any idea how I can resolve this issue?