# Mongodb: Query documents between two dates(Which is in String format "20-05-2019")

Tags: mongodb

I want to query documents in mongodb from my angular application which is in certain date range say, between "26-05-2019" and "01-06-2019". Here are few sample documents:

**Document 1:**

```
{
"timestamp" : "1558341279777",
"date" : "25-05-2019",
"hour" : "14",
"month" : "5",
"time" : "14:4:39",
"weekDay" : "Monday"
 }
```

**Document 2:**

```
{"timestamp" : "1558426047794",
"date" : "26-06-2019",
"hour" : "13",
"month" : "5",
"time" : "13:37:27",
"weekDay" : "Tuesday"
 }
```

**Document 3:**

```
{"timestamp" : "1558426047794",
"date" : "28-06-2019",
"hour" : "13",
"month" : "5",
"time" : "13:37:27",
"weekDay" : "Tuesday"
 }
```

**Document 4:**

```
{"timestamp" : "1558426047794",
"date" : "02-06-2019",
"hour" : "13",
"month" : "5",
"time" : "13:37:27",
"weekDay" : "Tuesday"
 }
```

**Requirement:** Fetch all documents between date range 26-05-2019 and 01-06-2019

**Expected Result:**

```
{"timestamp" : "1558426047794",
"date" : "26-06-2019",
"hour" : "13",
"month" : "5",
"time" : "13:37:27",
"weekDay" : "Tuesday"
 },     
{"timestamp" : "1558426047794",
"date" : "28-06-2019",
 "hour" : "13",
 "month" : "5",
 "time" : "13:37:27",
 "weekDay" : "Tuesday"
 }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Just `$lte` and `$gte` operator with the date using moment. `db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "$gte": [
          { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$dob", "format": "%d-%m-%Y" }},
          moment('26-05-2019').toDate()
        ]
      },
      {
        "$lte": [
          { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$dob", "format": "%d-%m-%Y" }},
          moment('01-06-2019').toDate()
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})`

Comment: @Fanpark really sorry for the confusion, actually I'm calling this query from my Angular application(typescript),its not javascript. And in my angular application, I'm getting 'null' for 'moment('01-06-2019').toDate()' :(
Any ideas?

Comment: Actually it was my fault. You need to provide "format" to the `moment()` as well. So change above dates to `moment('26-05-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY').toDate()`

Comment: @Fanpark No luck again :( The following is what is sent as query to mongodb:
'$expr': {
 '$and': [{
  '$gte': [{
   '$dateFromString': {
    'dateString': '$date',
    'format': '%d-%m-%Y'
   }
  }, '2019-05-25T18:30:00.000Z']
 }, {
  '$lte': [{
   '$dateFromString': {
    'dateString': '$date',
    'format': '%d-%m-%Y'
   }
  }, '2019-05-31T18:30:00.000Z']
 }]
}  
After using 'moment('26-05-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY').toDate()'

Comment: @Fanpark any idea? I'm really counting you on this man, please help

Comment: Now you are missing something else. And also check the type of the `moment('26-05-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY').toDate()`. It's type should be `object` not `string`. This is the only thing you are missing here. Else code is your's and you have to go with it.

Comment: @Fanpark, Just checked, 'moment('26-05-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY').toDate()' is of type string, not object. Not really sure whats happening. When I execute this query in mongoshell, I'm getting the expected output. The problem arises only when I try to do this programmatically(via Angular application)

Comment: @TonyMathew the best solution is to refactor your `date` field to either: 1) Use MongoDB's native `ISODate()` data type, which means that you can perform this query easily from MongoDB's side, or 2) Reformat to use `YYYY-MM-DD` format. This format is sortable, so you don't need to deal with date transformation. I realize this may not be practical for your use case, but you may want to reconsider using either solution for ease of maintenance in the future.